# My MVC 5 website is down unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-server-2012-r2

I hosted my MVC5 website in windows server **2012 R2** and it is working before couple of days.

When I checked the site on yesterday it is returning a white page. But it is authenticated by windows authentication. I checked the `IIS` log for and found It returns **200** successfully followed by **401** authentication negotiate. 
[image: IIS Log]

But I don't see any request for `CSS/JS` files. After status code 200 it is just blank.

[image: Page]

**Then I checked the event log and I found the below error:**

> 1/27/2017 21:05:01    Perflib 1023    None    Windows cannot load the
>   extensible counter DLL ASP.NET_64_2.0.50727. The first four bytes
>   (DWORD) of the Data section contains the Windows error code. 1/27/2017
>   21:05:01  Perflib 1023    None    Windows cannot load the extensible counter
>   DLL ASP.NET_2.0.50727. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data
>   section contains the Windows error code.

I am not sure whether this cause issue or not.

The thing is after this error site is not loading. Site is working as expected on Jan 27 morning. Please advice how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provide, it is hard to be sure, but it looks like your site application pool has been switched to .Net Framework 2 instead of 4.

Check in IIS console which application pool your site is using and check which .Net framework it runs.

Comment: I found root cause. Someone wrongly placed the virtual application's web.config into the root folder. So the application has crashed. After correcting web.config site is up and running.                                                                                                                  Thanks for you Frédéric.